# Select non-sibling elements using only CSS3

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have three blocs, each containing another bloc.
What I want is to select all the inner blocs when clicking on one of them.

Here's a Codepen illustrating my situation : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/viGDx

HTML

```
<div class="bloc-container">
  <div class="bloc"></div>
</div>

<div class="bloc-container">
  <div class="bloc"></div>
</div>

<div class="bloc-container">
  <div class="bloc"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
div.bloc-container {
  background-color: #D5CEFA;
  width: 300px;
  height:250px;
  display: inline-block;
}

div.bloc {
  background-color: #CEFAD5;
  width: 150px;
  height: 125px;
  margin: auto;

  transition: transform 0.2s ease-in;
}

div.bloc:active {
  transform        : scale(0.6);
  -moz-transform   : scale(0.6);
    -o-transform     : scale(0.6);
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.6);
}
```

I did it using the following Javascript code (commented in the Codepen):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var blocs = $('.bloc');

  blocs.bind('mousedown', function() {
    blocs.css('transform', 'scale(0.6)');
  });

  blocs.bind('mouseup', function() {
    blocs.css('transform', 'scale(1)');
  });
});
```

But I'm wondering how to do it using only CSS.

Comment: The closest you can do using just css is `body:active .bloc`.. just saying :)

Comment: Yeah, but I want the action to happen only while clicking on a bloc ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're looking for (the ability to select a 'cousin') would require a parent selector that could enable you to travel up DOM before coming back down again. Unfortunately CSS only provides selectors for descendants and siblings (not parents), neither of which can facilitate the behaviour you want.

I believe JavaScript is therefore required in this particular case.

- Reference - [CSS3 Selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#selectors)

Comment: It is also worth considering that there is no way to subscribe to click events in CSS - this is exactly the use case JavaScript was designed for. Since you have to use JavaScript to add the classes (best practice) or  inline-styles (avoid if possible) there is no advantage to using CSS to navigate the DOM, something else JavaScript is extremely good at.

Comment: The entire concept of events is foreign to CSS anyway (unless you want to consider the `pointer-events` property, but that property was borrowed from SVG, so...).

Answer (score 0):

You can do that (more or less) using `:active` pseudo-class in a parent:

CSS:

```
#wrapper:active .bloc {
    /* Your code */
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="bloc-container">
      <div class="bloc"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="bloc-container">
      <div class="bloc"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="bloc-container">
      <div class="bloc"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/7cbR6/3/)

Note that with CSS you can't always achieve exactly the same behavior than with JS, because CSS has no events.